Local WireGuard responing to a SSH TCP SYN to a wrong interface
I have a local WireGuard gateway that I am trying to manage using Ansible. I found an issue when connecting over SSH. That connection was getting timed out. After looking into the problem, I realized that the cause is that TCP SYN from SSH coming from interface ino1 is not getting SYN-ACK because the WG rule forwards it to the wg0 interface.
Does anyone know how to add a rule to the iptables that would fix this issue without conflicting with the WG traffic? WG runs on UDP.
I am not very skilled with iptables so any help will be appreciated.

enable verbosity and paste the output, I have a idea while I had a similar situation but with openvpn

I solved the issue in iptables, but then I found out that the server was sending SYN-ACK to wg0 because the server had last arp record to about the host from that interface. So I had to add masquarade to a dest-nat from the network where the host was (inaccessible for the server) to the server's NATed network

The solution was the question was:
# Mark incoming SYN packets and save the mark in the connection
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --syn -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
# Restore the mark to outgoing SYN,ACK packets
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add default dev ino1 table 100


nice to see remember to accept your own answer after 24 hour, else we will be reminded to solve the issue until the end of the universum

thanks for the reminder, I tried immediately but there was the 24 hour waiting period and then I forgot
